# Laravel 5.1 - Split content of table

Tags: php, mysql, sql, controller, laravel-5.1

I have this `mysql` table:

```
+----+-------------------------------+---------+--------------+-------------+
| id |             title             | chapter | date_release |   author    |
+----+-------------------------------+---------+--------------+-------------+
|  1 | This is should be title One   |       1 | 10/08/2015   | John Robert |
|  2 | This is should be title Two   |       1 | 11/08/2015   | John Robert |
|  3 | This is should be title Three |       1 | 12/08/2015   | John Robert |
|  4 | This is should be title Four  |       2 | 10/09/2015   | Sir Arthur  |
|  5 | This is should be title Five  |       2 | 11/09/2015   | Sir Arthur  |
|  6 | This is should be title Six   |       1 | 13/08/2015   | John Robert |
|  7 | This is should be title Seven |       2 | 12/08/2015   | Sir Arthur  |
+----+-------------------------------+---------+--------------+-------------+
```

In Laravel 5.1 I want to split from the table based `chapter` and result `view` like this:

```
<div class="chapter-1">
    <span>
    ...
    All content from table of chapter 1 only
    ...
    </span>
</div>
<div class="chapter-2">
    <span>
    ...
    All content from table of chapter 2 only
    ...
    </span>
</div>
```

I have no idea what query function should I do in the `controller` and how to display it in laravel `view`?

**EDITED:**

**@aldrin27** ask me about my controller, here it is.

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Book;
use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class BookController extends Controller {

    ...
    ...


    public function show($id) {
        //
        $book = Book::find($id);
        return view('books.show', compact('book'));
    }

    ...
    ...

}
```

Comment: Can i see your controller?

Comment: My `controller` is a standard Laravel controller which have `index`, `edit`, `show`, `store`, and else. And how should I show my controller function if I don't know how to do it like my question above? (still empty controller)

Comment: What controller that will query your data and pass it in view?

Comment: @aldrin27, `show` function.

Comment: Can i see that controller?

Comment: If you insist @aldrin27, I already add it into my question above.

Comment: Is your query of `$book` getting the expected result?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91797/discussion-between-wahyueka31-and-aldrin27).

Comment: Sorry can't chat right now. Chat room is blocked in my end.

Comment: The `controller` done well parsing plain laravel data from `model` into `view`. What I need is to split the result of that data table by `chapter`. If my controller show what I expect, then I needn't ask everyone here for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doing `Book::find($id)` will only return a model. What you want is to get a `Collection` of models to work with (eg: splitting, grouping, etc.). Use `all()` or `get()` instead.

Example, Do the following in your controller:

```
$books = Book::all();

$groupedBooks = $books->groupBy('chapter');
```

Pass `$groupedBooks` to your view and do something like the following in your view file:

```html
@foreach($groupedBooks as $chapter => $books)
    <div class="chapter-{{ $chapter }}">
        @foreach($books as $book)
            <p>{{ $book->title }}</p>
        @endforeach
    </div>
@endforeach
```

Note: I think there's a problem with how you setup your relationships. For example, a `Book` contains (zero or more?) `Chapter`, so those would be two related models instead of using just one model - `Book`. But that's just me...